# Raspbian Wifi does not see Wifi dongle on RP 2 B

Tags: raspbian, wifi

My Raspbian network panel does not see my wifi but I know that it is there.

iwlist wlan0 scan shows all of the wifi signals

I have added the SSID and PSK to my wpa_supplicant.conf file and still nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Add the `wpa_supplicant.conf` to the question body.